# How does scope in Javascript work?

Tags: javascript

I can not understand how scoping works in Javascript.
E.g.

```
<html>  
  <head>  
    <script>var userName = "George";  </script>
  </head>
  <body>  
     ......  
     <script>  
        document.write('Name = ' + userName);  
     </script>  
  </body>   
</html>
```

The variable `userName` is declared in another "section" of a script. As I understand it the browser renders html and executes code in the order it finds it. So how does `userName` in the second script tag gets resolved? Does it go to a global setting? Anything I declare earlier is global?
I noticed the same happens if I do something like:

```
<html>  
  <head>  
    <script>  
          do {  
              var userName = "George";   
              //bla  
          } while (someCondition);  
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>  
     ......  
     <script>  
        document.write('Name = ' + userName);  
     </script>  
  </body>   
</html>
```

Even when `userName` is declared inside `{}` it is still resolved in the second script. How is that possible?

Comment: 1. There is no blockscope in javascript. 2. `username` is declared in the global object `window`.

Answer (score 4):

Javascript scope is by function (ECMAScript 6 adds a `let` statement that introduces block scope as well). Everything that's not declared using `var` or `function` inside a function definition or a `let` block is in the global scope. There's just one global scope, shared by all `<script>` blocks. The `do` block does not introduce a new scope, so the variable declared there is visible in the later `document.write()`.

Comment: Good question. I admit it's not one of my better answers, but I think it addresses the poster's confusion.

Comment: It might have been down-voted because your assertion is not true. Preventing variables from being in the global scope inside a function block is prevented by using the `var` keyword. `function() { a = 1;}` - there `a` will be in the global scope. `function() { var a  = 1; }` - there `a` is not in the global scope.

Comment: OK, I've added a mention of the `var` and `function` keywords for defining local variables.

Answer (score 3):

The only scope in your example is the global scope. Different script blocks are DOM elements, and do not have their own javascript scope

[This is a great reference](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/tree/master/scope%20%26%20closures) for javascript scope.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you're creating the variable `userName` in the global `window` scope. Once you load your first example into the browser, open the JavaScript console and do a `console.log(window)`. You should see the `window` object dumped into the console. Open it up and you'll find the key "userName", with the value "George".

When you next reference the variable `userName` from within `document.write`, you're referencing it from the global scope.

If instead you had written a function, then called it from `document.write()`, you would no longer see it in the `window` scope, so long as you had declared it as a variable local to the function using the `var` keyword.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
    function foo() {
        var userName = "George";
        return 'Name = ' + userName;
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
     ......
     <script>
        document.write(foo());
     </script>
  </body>
</html>
```